# How to raise an event from the elements created using BrowserDomAdapter?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am creating elements using BrowserDomAdapter and appending them to view. I want to raise event when the newly created elements are clicked.But i am not successful.I have created a plunker demo so that somebody can help me http://plnkr.co/edit/VGHEPBs8oZW7HG6Ze21z?p=preview .

```
add(){
   var a=this.dom.createElement('button');
   this.dom.setInnerHTML(a,'clickme');
   this.dom.appendChild(this.dom.query("my-app"),a);
   a.createMouseEvent('onclick');
   a.createEvent(raiseevent);
   a.onclick=raiseevent;
 }
```

This is how i am adding an element and creating an event.And this the event which i want to run when element is clicked

```
raiseevent(){
   alert('hi');
 }
```

I want to know where i am doing wrong.Somebody guide me in the right way please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `on` method of the `BrowserDomAdapter` to set the listener. Also be sure to use `this` when referencing methods and properties on the class.

```
export class AppComponent {
  dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
  constructor() { 
    this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
  }
  add(){
    var a=this.dom.createElement('button');
    this.dom.on(a, 'click', this.raiseevent);
    this.dom.setInnerHTML(a,'clickme');
    this.dom.appendChild(this.dom.query("my-app"),a);
  }
  raiseevent(){
    alert('hi');
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow...Its very much easy.I thought we should create event using a.Createevent and couldnt get it...Thank you very much bro

Comment: But how can i pass parameters into it? If i write the code something like this--> this.dom.on(a,'click',this.raiseevent('hello')); The function executes in the beginning only...How can i solve that?

Comment: You can bind an argument to it using bind. `this.dom.on(a, 'click', this.raiseevent.bind(this, 'hello'));`

Comment: Thanks a lot brother

Comment: Sorry bro i am disturbing u continuously... Is there a way i can set localtemplate variable to the element created. Because I want the element created should have a localtemplate variable. I am able to set the id since it is an attribute but not localtemplate variable...

Comment: What do you mean by a `localtemplate` variable?

Comment: Means its similar to an id which i can use it anywhere in view...It will be something like this <div #child></div> where #child is the local template variable. The # prefix before "child" identifies the child as a local template variable. We can reference this variable within the template to access a child's properties.

Comment: @abhilashreddy I would recommend posting a new question about this with an example of your template and other relevant code as this is outside of the scope of this post.

Comment: Ok...I will post this one as a new question

Comment: Posted that question separately here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987560/is-it-possible-to-add-a-local-template-variable-using-browserdomadapter ...If possible have a look a it bro