# Is it possible to add a local template variable using BrowserDomAdapter?

Tags: typescript, angular

Hie...Is there a way i can set localtemplate variable to the element created. Because I want the element created should have a localtemplate variable. I am able to set the id since it is an attribute but not localtemplate variable.I have made a plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/VGHEPBs8oZW7HG6Ze21z?p=preview And i am trying to create it in the following way

```
add(){
var a=this.dom.createElement('button');
var b=this.dom.createTemplate('<div #child></div>');
this.dom.on(a, 'click', this.raiseevent.bind(this, this.op));
this.dom.setInnerHTML(a,'clickme');
this.dom.appendChild(this.dom.query("my-app"),a);
this.dom.appendChild(this.dom.query("my-app"),b);
this.op++;
```

}

Means its similar to an id which i can use it anywhere in view...It will be something like this  where #child is the local template variable. The # prefix before "child" identifies the child as a local template variable. We can reference this variable within the template to access a child's properties

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to inject the DOM elements in, the same can be accomplished with components?

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'child',
    template: `<button (click)="raiseevent()">clickme</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent{
    raiseevent(){
        // do something
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<child #child *ngFor="#item in children"></child>`,
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export AppComponent{
    children: any[] = [];

    add(){
        this.children.push({...});
    }
}
```

The end result will be the same. Each time the `add()` method is called, a new button will be added with it's own `raiseevent()` method. You can even have a child fire a method on the parent using an `EventEmitter`.

This does not take into account your `<div #child></div>` that you are injecting in because I do not know what your intentions are with that. If you could provide a more detailed example I could provide a more thorough answer. Though you could just as easily add the `<div>` to the `template` of `ChildComponent` and the end result would be the same.